# How to process HTTP callback which is been passed to return URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, callback

I have been stuck in a problem in which, I am making a post request to MBLOX HLR API to validate phone numbers like below,

https://hlrlookup.cardboardfish.com/HLRQuery?USERNAME=test&PASSWORD=test&RETURNTYPE=h&RETURNADDRESS=http://www.myurl.com&MSISDN=27837797094,27123456789

Which will return us a response like below:

> OK 267492492 267492493

And it will invoke a HTTP callback on RETURNADDRESS which we have specified above. It will be a GET request like below:

> GET
>   /hlr?Status=Invalid&Ported=No&ErrorCode=1&MSISDN=27123456789&QueryID=267492493&AccountID=1546&ErrorDescription=Unknown%20Subscriber
>   HTTP/1.1

Can someone tell me how would I process the above GET HTTP Callback on return address?

I'm using Express and following is my code I'm using:

```
app.post('/validatePhoneNumbers',function(req,res){
        body = "test";
        var lines = req.body.phoneNumbers;
        phoneNumberVlaidationResults = {};

        url = "http://hlrlookup.cardboardfish.com/HLRQuery?USERNAME=test&PASSWORD=test&RETURNTYPE=h&RETURNADDRESS=http://localhost:4000/validatePhoneNumbersCallback&MSISDN=" + lines;
        var request = http.get(url, function (response) {
            // data is streamed in chunks from the server
            // so we have to handle the "data" event    
            var buffer = "", 
                data,
                route;

            response.on("data", function (chunk) {
                buffer += chunk;
            }); 

            response.on("end", function (err) {
                //res.send(buffer);
                if(buffer!=''){
                    res.redirect('/validatePhoneNumbersCallback');
                }
            }); 
        }); 
        request.end();
});

app.get('/validatePhoneNumbersCallback',function(req,res){
    body = "test";
    console.log("validatePhoneNumbersCallback");
   //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
   console.log(req.param);
});
```